# Is searching possible in O(1) time?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, complexity-theory, big-o

I have a list of objects, `objectList`, where each object have several attributes one of these is `myUniqueNo`. `myUniqueNo` is a random integer for each object. I have an integer, say, `n`. I am sure that in `objectList` there is certainly an object that has the `myUniqueNo` as `n`. I want to return the object that have 'myUniqueNo' as `n`.  Is there any O(1) algorithm or simply a method in Java to return this object?

Comment: A hashtable with a perfect hash function will have an O(1) time.

Comment: Yep, sounds like you need a hash table

Comment: Sorry, actually i need to return the whole object not the position.. Then..? Please see the edit of question.

Comment: If the range of id values is small, then direct indexing might also be an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical approach for this would be to have an auxiliary `HashMap` that maps from the object to the position in the list.  Hash tables give expected amortized O(1) lookups, though if you try removing items from in the middle of the list you will have to do an extra O(n) work to update the hash table entries.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, actually i need to return the whole object not the position.. Then..?

Comment: @Rambo- In that case, just store the objects as the values in the `HashMap`.